# Get minutes elapsed dynamically with Google spreadsheet formula

Tags: google-sheets

I made a simple widget with IFTTT that notes the Date and Time in Google Spreadsheet when I click it.

See example: [image]

What I want to do is: make a formula on `D3` so that it gets the time elapsed from `C2` and `C3` in minutes:
`0:01`

Putting the formulas in `C3` gets me:

`=ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN() -1,4)` = `C2`

`=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN() -1,4)` = `C3`

Meaning, if I were to do `=C3-C2` I'd get `0:01:00`.

However, when I do something like:
`=(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN() -1,4)-ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN() -1,4))` (should just be C3-C2) I get an error:
`Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But 'C3' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.`

I tried using VALUE() to get the value of C3 and C2 and then get the difference but I'm kindof lost now.

You may notice I have very little experience with Google Spreadsheet formulas

**TLDR;**
`D3` should get me the time difference between

`(current column -1 )(current row)` minus `(current column -1)(current row -1)` in minutes

( `C3-C2` )

Comment: tag it as google spreadsheet issue...

Comment: @SolarMike done.

Comment: Not gonna post this as answer as this is not an Excel question anymore, but simple `=(C3-C2)*1440` and formatting as number seems good enough for me.

Comment: I think you should also edit out the part about Excel Formulas btw.

Comment: @M.Douda Thank you, I'll give it a shot. Sorry, I'm not using either as often or as intensive as some others and therefor do not know if there's much difference. I honestly thought Google Spreadsheet was somewhat of an online 'copy' of excel with the same functions/functionality. Apologies

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `ADDRESS()` and not simply referencing the cells `C3` and `C2`?

Comment: @Diego Yes, as every record is generated from another source (IFTTT), I want it to take the current row and not have a set value of C3/C2. Everytime a 'STOP' record is noted, I want the minutes elapsed between RecordBeforeCurrent and CurrentRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `TIMEVALUE()`, which will convert the "time" string into a time value, and you also need to combine the "Date" and "Time" values to get an accurate calculation (otherwise it will be assumed to all be the same date).

As you need the cell references to be input manually, your usage of `ADDRESS()` makes sense, but that only returns a String value of the cell address. You must then use `INDIRECT()` to get the value stored in that address.

```
=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-2,4))+TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1,4))))-(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-2,4))+TIMEVALUE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1,4))))
```

Finally, make sure to format the cell as a "Duration".

[image]

Comment: This works perfect, Diego. Is there any way to make the B3/C3 etc.. Dynamic? So when there's a new record on D5, in this case, it'll get the difference between C5 and C4

Comment: @Paramone Thanks for explaining why you were using `ADDRESS()`. I've modified the code above and will add an explanation now.

Comment: Absolutely perfect!! I can now make it so that, when a record is created, this formula is set on `(column)(row)` and it'll automatically get the difference. Thank you!!